# FileNotFound Error for string variable in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I stored a string of a list `temp` in a variable and then tried to add it to csv filename while converting a Pandas dataframe to CSV. But it constantly shows file not found error while converting. I have checked there is not file by that name as such it should create a new file.
List:

```
['May 20, 2014', 'Kennington Oval, London (day/night)', '11718', '667887', 'Only T20I at Kennington Oval, London (day/night)']
```

Code for csv conversion:

```
nameFile = temp[4]
df.to_csv(nameFile+".csv")
```

Error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Only T20I at Kennington Oval, London (day/night).csv'
```

Also `df.to_csv("abc"+str(1)+".csv")` works perfectly well.

Comment: you cannot have `/` in the file name

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit. Python cannot find the named file. It is likely that it is looking somewhere other than you expect. You probably need to supply the folder where the file lives. Start by specifying an absolute path.